# How to return updated rows from function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

i'm quite new to postgres. i want to create a function (like stored procedure) that updates multiple rows and selects affected rows.

here is my statement:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION set_val( 
                _val character varying(100) ) --5
            RETURNS setof "table_test" AS
$body$

declare results "table_test"%rowtype;

begin
    update  "table_test"
    set "value" = $1
    where   "gender" = 'm'
    returning * into results;

    if not found then 
        insert into "table_test"("value")
        values($1)
        returning * into results;
    end if;

    return next results;
end;    

$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

it works fine as long as only 1 row was affected. but when more rows are affected, it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a PL/pgSQL function has to return setof it has to use ["RETURN NEXT" or "RETURN QUERY"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN49837).

Comment: Please share some example for UPDATE query, I want to get  the number of rows updated.

Answer (score 2):

i finally got it
i use for loop with return next.
thanks

here's my code

```
declare result table1%rowtype;
begin
 for result in update table1 set ... where ... returning * loop
  return next result;
 end loop;
end;
```